# "Could not find type" error loading a form in the Windows Forms Designer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

I have a .NET 2.0 windows forms app, which makes heavy use of the `ListView` control.

I've subclassed the `ListView` class into a templated `SortableListView<T>` class, so it can be a bit smarter about how it displays things, and sort itself.

Unfortunately this seems to break the Visual Studio Forms Designer, in both VS2005 and 2008.

The program compiles and runs fine, but when I try view the owning form in the designer, I get these Errors:

- Could not find type 'MyApp.Controls.SortableListView'. Please make sure that the assembly that contains this type is referenced. If this type is a part of your development project, make sure that the project has been successfully built.

There is no stack trace or error line information available for this error

- The variable 'listViewImages' is either undeclared or was never assigned.

At MyApp.Main.Designer.cs Line:XYZ Column:1

```
Call stack:
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.Error(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String exceptionText, String helpLink)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeExpression(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String name, CodeExpression expression)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeExpression(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String name, CodeExpression expression)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeStatement statement)
```

The line of code in question is where it is actually added to the form, and is

```
this.imagesTab.Controls.Add( this.listViewImages );
```

listViewImages is declared as

```
private MyApp.Controls.SortableListView<Image> listViewImages;
```

and is instantiated in the `InitializeComponent` method as follows:

```
this.listViewImages = new MyApp.Controls.SortableListView<Image>();
```

As mentioned earlier, the program compiles and runs perfectly, and I've tried shifting the `SortableListView` class out to a seperate assembly so it can be compiled seperately, but this makes no difference.

I have no idea where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> when you added the listview, did you add it to the toolbox and then add it to the form?

No, I just edited `Main.Designer.cs` and changed it from `System.Windows.Forms.ListView` to `MyApp.Controls.SortableListView<Image>`

Suspecting it might have been due to the generics led me to actually finding a solution.

For each class that I need to make a SortableListView for, I defined a 'stub class' like this

```
class ImagesListView : SortableListView<Image> { }
```

Then made the `Main.Designer.cs` file refer to these stub classes instead of the `SortableListView`.

It now works, hooray!

Thankfully I am able to do this because all my types are known up front, and I'm only using the `SortableListView` as a method of reducing duplicate code.

Comment: Hi Orion... I have the same problem as you mentioned above... I wasn't able to understand the part                                                                                                                                 "     For each class that I need to make a SortableListView for, I defined a 'stub class' like this

class ImagesListView : SortableListView<Image> { } "                         what did you do to resolve this issue ? can you explain in little detail ? Did you create another new class and then referred that to designer.cs ?

Comment: Aparently 9 people understood this and made it work for them. Could anyone explain what do do, like Gowtham I do not understand what to do?

Answer (score 43):

It happened to me because of x86 / x64 architecture.

Since Visual Studio (the development tool itself) has no x64 version, it's not possible to load x64 control into GUI designer.

The best approach for this might be tuning GUI under x86, and compile it for x64 when necessary.

Comment: Sure enough, changing my target CPU to x86 fixed this problem for me. Thanks!

Comment: This is such complete BS on Microsoft's part.

Comment: I really want an x64 version of Visual Studio.

Comment: This solution led me to the right path! Even in VS 2019, the project containing your forms should really target "AnyCPU" and if you must call into a x64 library from a user control or overridden control, protect that call with checks against the control's `DesignMode` property, and if the control is uses types in the x64 code in member variables, you need to turn them into `object` types and cast as necessary within the functions. Remember Windows Forms Designer will attempt to instantiate the class.

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem too, related to merging massive SVN changes (with conflicts) in the *.Designer.cs file. The solution was to just open up the design view graphically, edit a control (move it to the left then right) and resave the design. The *.Designer.cs file magically changed, and the warning went away on the next compilation.

To be clear, you need to fix all of the code merge problems first. This is just a work around to force VS to reload them.

Comment: This is simply not true. If you get any of these warnings, then the graphical view is broken. Nothing will show and so you cannot "move something around to magically fix it". There is just a list of errors and no gui as the op is complaining about.

Comment: I disagree strongly; this worked for me like a charm (using Framework 4.0). When initially displaying the designer warnings shoed up for a few seconds, then the form was drawn properly. I added a button, deleted the button, and rebuilt the solution; the warnings all disappeared.

Comment: Dirk - you can think it is not true, but this is what happened to me. I spent hours to trying to fix it. I wish I still had the before and after versions of the Designer.cs file, but I don't. There's clearly a bug in Visual Studio that doesn't properly refresh some internal meta data, and the only way I found to fix it is to force a refresh by resaving the graphical view.

Comment: please don't down vote this if you think this is not true. There is a bug in Visual Studio in the way it caches the design files and this is a work around. Of course, you need to fix the errors first and then do this work around to get Visual Studio past it.

Comment: Worked for me in VS 2015. Something in the designer code was probably added in the wrong order. (Did click on "Proceed to Design View" first so I could modify layout in Designer.)

Comment: Yay, this worked for me with VS 2022. I did some massive refactoring and had this issue. Clicking "ignore and continue" to add and remove a label did it for me.

Answer (score 6):

I've had a problem like this (tho not the same) in the past where my control was in a different namespace to my form even tho it was in the same project. To fix it I had to add a

```
using My.Other.Namespace;
```

to the top of the designer generated code file. The annoying thing was it kept getting blown away when the designer regenerated the page.

Comment: Same problem in VS2013, eventually fixed by changing build target platform to Any CPU from x64. Deleting bin and obj dirs caused more problems.

Answer (score 2):

The assembly that contains MyApp.Controls.SortableListView isn't installed in the GAC by any chance is it?

Answer (score 2):

when you added the listview, did you add it to the toolbox and then add it to the form?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you forgot to add that:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Release all resources used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be removed otherwise; false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        // ...
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container(); // Not necessarily, if You do not use
        // ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem. After removing some of my own controls of the *.Designer.cs-File the problem was solved. After going back to the original code the problem still was solved. So it seems to be a problem with the Visual Sudio cache. At the moment I cannot reproduce this problem.

If you have the problem try to emtpy the folder

C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\VERSION\Designer\ShadowCache

Did it work?

Comment: I was having an issue loading up a designer (VS 2017, .NET 4.7.1) that I started on a different machine. The custom control designer was fine, it compiled ok, but the form designer wouldn't load correctly until I deleted the ShadowCache.

Answer (score 1):

I had something similar - a user control was referring to a remote serice (which I couldn't guarantee being available at design time).

[This post on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/6d3147b0-8343-44aa-a191-f0e58b96c7ea) suggested that I add

```
if (this.DesignMode) return;
```

to the Load function of the control, or in my case to the point before the WCF client was initialised. That did the trick.

So

```
private readonly Client _client = new Client();
```

becomes

```
private Client _client;

public new void Load()
{
    if(DesignMode) return;
    _client = new Client();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. In my case this issue was due to resource initialization. I moved the following code from `InitializeComponent` method to ctor(After calling `InitializeComponent`). After that this issue was resolved:

```
this->resources = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager(XXX::typeid));
```

Answer (score -3):

In my case the problem was the folder's name of my project! Why I think this:
I use SVN and in the 'trunk\SGIMovel' works perfectly. But in a branch folder named as 'OS#125\SGIMovel' I can't open the designer for a form that uses a custom control and works in the trunk folder.

Just get off the # and works nice.