# VS 2008 designer "Could not find type...."

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, compact-framework

I'm getting this error in visual studio 2008 in a Mobile Desktop application .NET 3.5.

Could not find type 'MyNamespace.MyType'. Please make sure that the assembly that contains this type is referenced. If this type is a part of your development project, make sure that the project has been successfully built.

This shows up when opening a form.  The type that it can't reference is a user control that is part of the same project.  Nothing is wrong with the namespaces.  This is maddening -- the project builds just fine.

Also, the referenced control is not a generic class like in this article: ["Could not find type" error loading a form in the Windows Forms Designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314/could-not-find-type-error-loading-a-form-in-the-designer)

**UPDATE:** well now later it seems to be working.  This seems to be a sporadic problem...

Comment: Might be worth looking at the accepted answer for [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408002/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-xxxx-or-one-of-its-dependencies-the-system-can/422517#422517)

Comment: (+1) I agree, a change in assembly version is potentially an issue. When you see this message, delete all copies of the dll before you recompile.  It sounds like it is finding a different version of the dll than it was compiled for.

Comment: Pedro's answer fixed it for me. A clean build didn't work so I deleted the bin folder. Then hit rebuild and it has fixed it. In my case I renamed the project rather than changing version numbers

Answer (score 1):

Is the actual line that is causing a problem in the Form.designer.cs/vb file?  Occasionally there are name qualification issues that result in the error you are seeing. Try opening up the designer file and changing the name as follows

C#

```
global::MyNamespace.MyType
```

VB.Net

```
Global.MyNamespace.MyType
```

After that, rebuild and reopen the designer

Comment: Didn't work.  Initially the declaration was just "MyType ucMyType1" since the user control and the form are in the same namespace.  But neither MyNamespace.MyType nor global::MyNamespace.MyType fixed anything.

There is no line number -- the warning for "Could not load type" has row/col blank.